# reboot windows mobile 6.5 professional from c# application

Tags: windows, mobile, shutdown, reboot

I am using the following code to reboot the device from my c# application

```
[Flags]
    public enum ExitFlags
    {
        Reboot = 0x02,
        PowerOff = 0x08
    }

    [DllImport("coredll")]
    public static extern int ExitWindowsEx(ExitFlags flags, int reserved);

ExitWindowsEx(ExitFlags.PowerOff, 0);
```

however i get the following error:

```
Can't find an Entry Point 'ExitWindowsEx' in a PInvoke DLL 'coredll'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because the function ExitWindowsEx doesn't exist in coredll it exists in aygshell.dll

Have a look at the information here http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/aygshell.ExitWindowsEx